# Array contains anything other than 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers with 64 indexes (it's canvas image data).

I want to know if my array contains only zero's or anything other than zero.

We can return a boolean upon the first encounter of any number greater than zero (even if the very last index is non-zero and all the others are zero, we should return true).

What is the most efficient way to determine this?

Of course, we could loop over our array (focus on the `testImageData` function):

```js
// Setup
var imgData = {
  data: new Array(64)
};
imgData.data.fill(0);
// Set last pixel to black
imgData.data[imgData.data.length - 1] = 255;

// The part in question...
function testImageData(img_data) {
  var retval = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < img_data.data.length; i++) {
    if (img_data.data[i] > 0) {
      retval = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return retval;
}

var result = testImageData(imgData);
```

...but this could take a while if my array were bigger.

Is there a more efficient way to test if any index in the array is greater than zero?

I am open to answers using lodash, though I am not using lodash in this project. I would rather the answer be native JavaScript, either ES5 or ES6. I'm going to ignore any jQuery answers, just saying...

**Update**

I setup a test for various ways to check for a non-zero value in an array, and the results were interesting.

[**Here is the JSPerf Link**](https://jsperf.com/finding-anything-other-than-zero)

Note, the `Array.some` test was much slower than using `for (index)` and even `for-in`. The fastest, of course, was `for(index)` *for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)...*.

You should note that I also tested a Regex solution, just to see how it compared. If you run the tests, you will find that the Regex solution is much, much slower (not surprising), but still very interesting.

I would like to see if there is a solution that could be accomplished using bitwise operators. If you feel up to it, I would like to see your approach.

Comment: Have you tried this and found it ‘inefficient’? How fast do you need it to be? How fast is it now? For any performance question, first start with measurement.

Comment: No, there's no faster way, and that's not slow. If you really care about the speed of this operation (and if so, have you measured it?), then you could maintain a boolean which you update when you write to the array.

Comment: There's no way to check occurrence of an element in an array without iterating over all the elements in the array. And if the last element is 255, you don't even need to check.

Comment: `img_data.data.some(x => x)` will be true if there's any non-zero data -  `.some` is "native code" so *may* be faster - note, your `testImageData` function is flawed, it always returns `img_data` and `retval` is unused

Comment: I agree with all the previous comments.  The only other thing that might be possible, depending on your conditions, is to make the array a property of an object, like { objArray: theArray, hasData: true/false } and set "hasData" as you are defining each of the array's elements.  If you can do this as you build the array, you don't need to iterate the array.

Comment: Your function really does nothing! You are returning img_data and you have not manipulated it at all. retval is never seen outside the function. So result would be equal to image_data.

Comment: @habamedia Apparently I made a simple mistake. That should have been obvious. I've updated my question to fix it. Thanks for the downvotes everybody!

Comment: @JaromandaX `Array.prototype.some` appears to be exactly what I was talking about, though I am not sure if it is any more efficient than looping the array myself and returning on the first occurrence of a passing test. This does, however, reduce the code to one line and clean things up. Thank you!

Comment: The speed for this operation really isn't that important in my application and has not caused me any issues, I was just curious if there was a faster or cleaner way to do this after I wrote it.

Comment: I've done extensive research on `Array.protoype` now (just out of curiosity). There is a lot of really interesting stuff there that I was unaware of before. I suggest checking it out. From what I have found, [**Array.prototype.some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) truly is the best option. @JaromandaX If you post `Array.prototype.some` with the [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), I will be sure to accept it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is the fastest way on Chrome 64 with Windows 10.

I've tested against two other options, [here is the link to the test](https://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-com-questions-48512185) so you can run them on your environment.

My results are:

```
// 10776 operations per second (the best)
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] !== 0) {
    break
  }
}

// 4131 operations per second
for (const n of arr) {
  if (n !== 0) {
    break
  }
}

// 821 operations per second (the worst)
arr.some(x => x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the testing! This is exactly what I wanted to see!

Answer (score 0):

There is no faster way than looping through every element in the array. logically in the worst case scenario the last pixel in your array is black, so you have to check all of them. The best algorithm therefore can only have a O(n) runtime. Best thing you can do is write a loop that breaks early upon finding a non-white pixel.